# profit maximization problem (optimization)

Tags: optimization, maximize

I would like to perform the optimization of a variable X (profit) that depends on a variable Y; however, the Y variable (action) depends on the X variable.

For example, the variable Y(action) in position 1 does not give me a profit to be made for position 1 of X(profit). However, this action for position 3 (FUTURE) makes sense, because the sum of what happened in 1, 2 and 3 gives a higher value than not doing the action in 1.

Does anyone know how you can perform this profit maximization other than with conditionals in python?
Is there a library that you can recommend and code example?

Using conditionals I managed to cover a lot of the problem, but I always get an exception. so I would like a bookstore that explores all possibilities. in a future of i=70